# The variable 'MyException' is declared but never used

Tags: c#, .net, exception, frameworks, ambiguity

I need to clear this warning :

```
try
{
    doSomething()
}
catch (AmbiguousMatchException MyException)
{
    doSomethingElse()
}
```

The complier is telling me :

> The variable 'MyException' is declared but never used

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

1. You can remove it like this:

   ```
   try
   {
       doSomething()
   }
   catch (AmbiguousMatchException)
   {
       doSomethingElse()
   }
   ```
2. Use warning disable like this:

   ```
   try
   {
       doSomething()
   }
   #pragma warning disable 0168
   catch (AmbiguousMatchException exception)
   #pragma warning restore 0168
   {
       doSomethingElse()
   }
   ```

Other familiar warning disable

```
#pragma warning disable 0168 // variable declared but not used.
#pragma warning disable 0219 // variable assigned but not used.
#pragma warning disable 0414 // private field assigned but not used.
```

Comment: A list of all compiler errors and warnings are available at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228296(v=VS.80).aspx)

Comment: The solution given by @fparadis2 is better since not advisable to supress warnings when we can fix it

Comment: @dasariramacharanprasad that was my first suggestion, re-read my answer ;)

Comment: solution #2 is not a solution, it is a mask.

Comment: But it is a sharp one isn't it :)

Comment: #2 is useful when you want to look at the exception in the debugger or use it in debug only code. (Yes, I realize that #if DEBUG blocks introduce a code smell of their own.)

Comment: yes but this answer is a bit TLDR whilst Khepri & fparadise2 is short and sweet, why even suggest any hacks, you can just ignore all errors and warnings in your head as well :-) I know some devs do that a lot :)

Answer (score 44):

You declare a name for the exception, MyException, but you never do anything with it. Since it's not used, the compiler points it out.

You can simply remove the name.

```
catch(AmbiguousMatchException)
{
   doSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 31):

You can simply write:

```
catch (AmbiguousMatchException)
```

and omit the exception name if you won't be using it in the catch clause.

Comment: +1 since it resolves the warning! not explained in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(RETHROWTOPRESERVESTACKDETAILS);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true).

Answer (score 3):

You could write the exception out to a log if you've got one running.  Might be useful for tracking down any problems.

```
Log.Write("AmbiguousMatchException: {0}", MyException.Message);
```

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is, you aren't using your variable `MyException` anywhere.  It gets declared, but isn't used.  This isn't a problem... just the compiler giving you a hint in case you intended to use it.

Answer (score 1):

`but never used` means that you should use it after catch() such as writing its value to console, then this warning message will disappear.

```
catch (AmbiguousMatchException MyException)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MyException); // use it here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this, where the exception was used based upon compiler variables...

Anyway, my solution was:

```cs
 _ = MyException;
```

Picks it up as used, acknowledges that it isn't really being used.